# Access structure in Attributes Based Encryption

Tags: abe, monotone-access-structure

I thought that access structure and access tree are equivalent but I've read in a [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6382815) (page 3) that there are at least three types of access structures :

- AND gates
- Access tree
- LSSS generating matrix

I would like to know what is the difference between them, are they equivalent or some of them are more expressive (better to use) than others?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add link to paper...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've just edited my question, I added a link to the paper.

Comment: You haven't yet [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) (or it seems to me even upvoted) any answer to your previous questions. Please revisit them and see if they solve your problem.